# Is PDO really better than MySQLi if I'm only using MySQL databases?

Tags: php, pdo, mysqli

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [mysqli or PDO - what are the pros and cons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13569/mysqli-or-pdo-what-are-the-pros-and-cons)

I got something working using MySQLi, but I'm reading everywhere that PDO is superior, however, so far, the most important thing is the possibility to connect to other type of databases and not only to MySQL.

Do you know of any other advantage of using PDO over MySQLi ?

Thanks.

Comment: It's just subjective API preferences, and the flexibility advantage you already mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

As far as mySQL is concerned, they are more or less equivalent. It mostly boils down to what you are most familiar with.

Answer (score 1):

This page compares the two:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use/

Check out the pros and cons and decide for yourself based on your requirements.